# Scaling periodic tasks in celery

Tags: celery

We have a 10 queue setup in our celery, a large setup each queue have a group of 5 to 10 task and each queue running on dedicated machine and some on multiple machines for scaling.

On the other hand, we have a bunch of periodic tasks, running on a separate machine with single instance, and some of the periodic tasks are taking long to execute and I want to run them in 10 queues instead.

Is there a way to scale celery beat or use it purely to trigger the task on a different destination "one of the 10 queues"?

Please advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [celery routing](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/routing.html) to dispatch the task to where you need: